# Configuration recovery on Extreme Networks Summit 200

Tags: switch, management

I need to upgrade a small network I know nothing about.

The only manageable switch in an Extreme Networks Summit 200, running ExtremeWare 7.3 (from 2005!). Of course, the default admin password has been changed (and nobody has any idea who configured those switches in the first place).

In order to migrate to a newer switch, I need to access the current config of the Summit switch, then translate the config to the new one.

**How can I recover the current configuration without knowing the admin password?**

*More details:*

I can put the switch offline for some time (out of office hours). I cannot loose the config.

The company does not have any support plan with Extreme Networks.

Using BootROM, I can load default config and boot. Here, I have admin access, but I cannot find a way to dump/recover the primary config of the switch.

There are several ways to recover the config on EXOS available on the web. These methods feature sending/editing the file containing the configuration like [here](https://gtacknowledge.extremenetworks.com/articles/How_To/How-to-Recover-A-Switch-And-Its-Configuration-Without-The-Password).

However, on my ExtremeWare version, I only have the following commands:

`Available commands:
        <cr> abort clear configure create delete disable download enable exit 
        history logout mrinfo mtrace nslookup ping quit reboot restart rtlookup 
        run save scp2 show ssh2 telnet traceroute unconfigure upload use`

`upload` is interesting, but from the documentation, it can only upload (via tftp) the current config.

There is a single instance on the web of the existence of a hidden debug mode [here](https://mailman.nanog.org/pipermail/nanog/2016-August/087398.html). However, as the email states, this debug mode needs a deep understanding of the system to be useful.

Here is everything I did until now. Any Extreme guru here to help me out?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you not have any access at all (and did you test these commands on another switch), or do you only have access with a normal user account?

Comment: I have no access to the switch when the primary configuration is being loaded. I used BootROM to load the default config and get access to the switch as admin. Even as admin on the default config, I don't know how to find the primary config. Does that clarify?

Comment: Yes, this clears things up.. Too bad I don't know much Extremeware anymore.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you followed these steps? https://gtacknowledge.extremenetworks.com/articles/How_To/How-to-Recover-A-Switch-And-Its-Configuration-Without-The-Password

Comment: I mentioned this link in my question. I cannot do it because I don't have either "vi" or "tftp" command.

Comment: You probably have to 'enable' first before the editing commands become available... years later. ;)